# recognition first letter in input stream

Tags: java, input

hello i have this method which is serving my input stream.

```
private String getMessage(InputStream in) throws IOException {

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     int pom;

     while((pom = in.read()) != -1){             
        char znak = (char) pom;
        sb.append(znak);                   

        if (sb.toString().contains("\r\n")) {                  
               String result = sb.toString();                                       
               result = result.replace("\r\n", "");
               return result;
        }
     }   
     return null;
}
```

I would like to recognize if the first written letter is 'I' or not. If it is not 'I' i want to terminate the input. How can i get the first letter and immediately test it?

Comment: char c = string.charAt(0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the first character in the StringBuffer :

```
   private String getMessage(InputStream in) throws IOException {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            int pom;

            while((pom = in.read()) != -1){             
               char znak = (char) pom;
               sb.append(znak);                   
               if ( sb.charAt(0) != 'I')
                   break;
               if (sb.toString().contains("\r\n")) {                  
                      String result = sb.toString();                                       
                      result = result.replace("\r\n", "");
                      return result;
               }
            }   
            return null;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `Reader`! Right now you use an `InputStream` and this reads bytes, not characters.

This means you also need to know the encoding of your stream.

Supposing this is UTF-8, you can do:

```
String line;

try (
    BufferedReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
) {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        if (line.charAt(0) == 'l')
            break;
}
```

Note that a `BufferedReader`'s `.readLine()` automatically strips newlines.

Comment: I know, because of some reasons I need to receive information byte by byte. Sry, I had to tell it in the first message.

Comment: There is no reason for that. Don't forget that a Reader really reads the underlying bytes and then converts them to characters on the fly.

Comment: omg... Yes, there is reason. My teacher is my reason. When he says do it with InputStream byte by byte i have no choice. ;)

Comment: Well then your teacher is very, very stupid! Show him [this link](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.com/2014/03/strings-characters-bytes-and-character.html)

Comment: Yeah... That's not new information. :D Okay, let's i will use your way. The first if condition (if character == 'l') will check every character in the stream. Or?

Comment: Yes. Hey, you asked character by character ;) There are of course shorter ways to do that, but you said you wanted to "terminate the input" as soon as you encountered this letter ;)

Comment: okay my fault. Let's say I will be receiving messages like "Info 123\r\n", "Info hello Im alex\r\n" etc. And I need to check only the first letter in the sentence. For example "nfo 123" is wrong sentence and i need to terminate it after recognizing it.

Comment: well...its for server application using telnet connection. Its not very suitable to use deadline. ;)

Comment: Uuuh, then there are methods to read into a char array, a `CharBuffer`... (on a `CharBuffer` you can use a regex btw)